# How does LoadRunner recognize that data has been returned?

Tags: load-testing, loadrunner

If I e.g. record an action that is querying database and the result is returned after 1 minute, how does Loadrunner recognize this? Because it appears in the communication between client and server?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loardrunner makes a HTTP request in a thread, and then that thread waits for it to return until the timeout period. 
When the request returns with a response, LoadRunner parses it and based on your code, can extract any information from it. It can also easily measure the time it waited to get the response.

Comment: Thanks, so I do not need any special code when I recorded the process and stopped recording when the GUI rendered the results?

Comment: During recording, no special code is required. However you will have to modularize the code, parameterize it and then make sure that you create the correct scenarios for load testing.